# strange error of jquery sibling('.class') in my case

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
console.log((this).sibling('.advanceOptWrap'));
```

Above code return error of Uncaught TypeError: $(...).sibling is not a function.

My DOM look like this

[image]

Comment: It's `.siblings()` (plural) - it's often a lot quicker to go straight to [the documentation](http://api.jquery.com) to solve problems like this.

Comment: Oh also you forgot to invoke jQuery. `$(this).siblings(...)`

Answer (score -1):

```
var advanceOptWrap = jQuery(this).sibling(".advanceOptWrap");
console.log(advanceOptWrap);
//alert(advanceOptWrap);
```

Comment: Please consider editing your answer to include an explanation of how your code works.